# Get http request data in Django Url Dispatcher? Is this possible? If so, how?

Tags: python, django, httprequest, django-urls, django-authentication

I would like to conditionally route urls in my django application based upon the contents of the http request, similar to this:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated() and request.user.is_staff():
       #provide a specific set of urls
elif request.user.is_authenticated():
       #provide alternative urls
else
       #provide default urls
```

I would like to do this inside the url dispatcher inside my application, as I would like certain urls to be completely unavailable to a user if they are not logged in. I feel that doing it this way would be much cleaner than pointing to views to determine what is rendered. Has anyone ever done this? Is this even possible in Django? Thanks

Comment: why not decorate views with permission instead of urls?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible. The urls file isn't read each time a request comes in. It runs when you start up an instance of django before requests are being handled.

The suggestion made by user995394 would be the way I would handle it.

Digging a bit deeper if you did want to do this. You could specify a request middleware.

```
class FooMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            request.urlconf = 'myproject.authed_urls2'
```

I tested the above middleware in a django project. When I login the alternate file is handled for that request while in another window a non authenticated user is still using the original url conf.

Still though, I recommend using decorators on your views. If you are concerned with people discovering urls that only staff should know about you can have your auth required decorator respond with `NotFound` instead of `NotAuthorized`

Comment: Yes, but you can have multiple urls.py and and switch which one you use for a given request (but that's rather involved - and IMHO useless - hacking).

Answer (score 1):

This might be possible either with a custom middleware (in the `process_request` part) or by monkey `patching core.handlers.BaseHandler.get_response()`, but really using decorators (which can be done in your urls.py files too) is the sane way to go.

Comment: I've been looking into custom middleware and using the process_request function. Unfortunately, It doesn't appear as though there is a way to  do what I initially posted about using custom middleware. I'm going to be looking into decorators as the possible solution.

Comment: I got it to work after I posted my answer. I didnt try any thing crazy though, just blanked the urlconf in the request

Comment: Blanking is one thing, replacing is another.

Comment: Yeah, wasn't sure of the format but took a look at urlresolvers.py. I was able to get a completely different urls.py file running by passing a string to the module in requesst.urlconf

Comment: Uhu. I didn't have time to look further, but now I know. Hats off, Sir <g>